# How to update column with incremental value using tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wanna update first and last name of one table with incremental value. For example:-

```
ID   FirstName  
1    Demo_01    
2.   Demo_02
3.   Demo_03
4.   And so on....
```

This table has 1000s of records. But for demo purposes we do not want to share real Name. So Please help how to update First Name with "Demo_ + Incremental value by one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT FirstName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RN
FROM YourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET FirstName = 'Demo_ ' + CAST(RN AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Or do you mean you want to use the ID field directly?

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET FirstName = 'Demo_ ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10))
```

NB: You say you have thousands of records but obviously they won't fit in the `Demo_01` format. Say you want to allow up to 6 digits and pad with leading zeroes you could use something like.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET FirstName = 'Demo_ ' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)),6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the CTE:

```
DECLARE @NewID INT;

SET @NewID = 0;

UPDATE myTable
SET @NewID = ID = @NewID + 1

UPDATE myTable
SET FirstName = 'Demo_ ' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)),6)
```

Answer (score -1):

For MySQL

```
UPDATE tablename SET FirstName = CONCAT('Demo_',ID);
```

Comment: Except he asked for TSQL, not MySQL

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I missed that.